# define the environment variable JAVA_HOME

Tags: ubuntu-11.04

where can I define the environment variable JAVA_HOME (export JAVA_HOME=path)? I'm using ubuntu 11.10
thanks for help

Comment: I've you accepted previous answers people would be more likely to help you.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to set it only for your user, it should be under : ~/.pam_environment - This file is specifically meant for setting a user's environment. It is not a script file, but rather consists of assignment expressions, one per line.

If you want to set it system-wide it should be under : /etc/environment - This file is specifically meant for system-wide environment variable settings. It is not a script file, but rather consists of assignment expressions, one per line. Specifically, this file stores the system-wide locale and path settings.

All the information and details can be found at : [Environment Variables](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables)

Comment: thaknks for your answer. I added this syntax: JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-openjdk"  to the /etc/environment file. TYping echo $JAVA_HOME , the path does not appear in the console. Is something wrong??

Answer (score 0):

Add it to the bottom of your ~/.bashrc file